# I can't understand 'RDD.map{ case (A, B) => A } ' in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm relatively new to Scala Spark. I've got a question with map method.

My understanding: map is a RDD method, it accepts a function as its parameter like:`map(line => line.split(","))`

I found really hard to understand this kind of expression.

```
val uniqueUsers = data.map { case (user, product, price) => user }.distinct().count()
```

Could someone explain two things for me:

1. why {} is used not ()
2. can I regard `case (user, product, price) => user` as a function? If not, what is it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Scala the syntax `{ case arg => body }` is a [Partial Function](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/PartialFunction.html).

definition of Partial Function from Scala-Doc

> A partial function of type PartialFunction[A, B] is a unary function
>   where the domain does not necessarily include all values of type A.
>   The function isDefinedAt allows to test dynamically if a value is in
>   the domain of the function.

In your case  of `{ case (user, product, price) => user }` you have defined a Partial Function that a takes a Tuple3 object as input. This Tuple3 object is unpacked as 3 variables of `user`, `product` and `price` and the function body just returns the `user`.

so to answer your questions

1. why {} is used not ()

   *because partial functions have to be wrapped by curly braces.*
2. an I regard case (user, product, price) => user as a function? If not, what is it?

   *yes. `{ case (user, product, price) => user }` is a special type of Function called [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/PartialFunction.html) which is defined only for specific inputs and is not defined for other inputs. In your case the PartialFunction is defined only for input of `Tuple3[T1,T2,T3]` where T1,T2, and T3 are types of user,product and price objects*

Comment: Thanks! `{ case (user, product, price) => user }` is a special Function PartialFunction. But `data.map({ case (user, product, price) => user })` seems easier to understand, is it also legal?

Comment: `data.map({ case (user, product, price) => user })` is legal. you are just passing the partialfunction `({ case (user, product, price) => user }` as input to your map function. in scala `object.funtion(arg)` and `object function arg` both are valid and you can use either.